# How to get the name of the file which I want to upload using multipart

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets, upload

I want to fetch the name of the file which I am uploading.
The aim is get full path of the file (including file name with extention).
jsp:-

```
<form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>  
        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>  

 </form>
```

servlet:-

```
        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.setContentType("text/html");  
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
      String filename=request.getParameter("fname"); //unable to get fname
MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");
String filePath="d:/new".concat(filename);
out.print("successfully uploaded");   
out.print(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**A.Plain Servlet Solution:**

**1. Get [javax.servlet.http.Part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) from HttpServletRequest**

```
   String fileName = null;
        //Get all the parts from request and write it to the file on server
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            fileName = getFileName(part);
          }
```

**2. Get filename from Part**

```
   /**
     * Utility method to get file name from HTTP header content-disposition
     */
    private String getFileName(Part part) {
        String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
        System.out.println("content-disposition header= "+contentDisp);
        String[] tokens = contentDisp.split(";");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            if (token.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                return token.substring(token.indexOf("=") + 2, token.length()-1);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

===================================================

**B.Spring based Solution:**

With spring, When you upload a file, `request` is the instance of [**org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html)

You can get uploaded filename from MultipartHttpServletRequest as below.

```
   // cast request
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    // get filenames as iterator

    Iterator<String> iterator = multipartRequest.getFileNames();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String uploadedFileName = (String) iterator.next();

    }
```

Comment: No.I am not using Spring.

Comment: Can you share fully qualified name of MultipartRequest ?

Comment: The plain solution is pretty neat, thanks! Googled a while only to find a bunch of library-related solutions